# pod-identity-webhook missing after EKS 1.16 upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

After upgrading to EKS 1.16, [IAM Roles for Service Account](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/) stopped working.
It was configured as described in the article, configuring and assigning service accounts to pods, and worked with EKS 1.14 and 1.15.

Running **service-account.yaml** and **test-pod.yaml** on EKS 1.15 (qa env) does mount the following env variables

```
AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/oidc-my-service-api-qa
AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
```

While running same resources on EKS 1.16 (test env), they are not added.

**service-account.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/oidc-my-service-test
  name: oidc-my-service-service-account
```

**test-pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "env | grep AWS"]
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1000
  serviceAccountName: "oidc-my-service-service-account"
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out I'm missing [Amazon EKS Pod Identity Webhook](https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook), but where did it go?

EKS 1.15

```
kubectl get mutatingwebhookconfigurations pod-identity-webhook
NAME                   CREATED AT
pod-identity-webhook   2020-01-11T17:01:52Z
```

EKS 1.16

```
kubectl get mutatingwebhookconfigurations pod-identity-webhook
Error from server (NotFound): mutatingwebhookconfigurations.admissionregistration.k8s.io "pod-identity-webhook" not found
```

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the service account. Can you post the output of `kubectl get sa <YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME> -o yaml`, making sure to redact any sensitive information?  Also, can you post the output of `kubectl get pod <YOUR_POD_NAME> -o yaml` again redacting anything sensitive.

Comment: @BrianPursley thanks, I was able to narrow down the problem. service account does not add env variables to my pod, updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to re-install [amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook](https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook) in my EKS 1.16 cluster by cloning the code from github, building docker image and pushing it to my ECR repo, and running

```
make cluster-up IMAGE=my-account-id.dkr.ecr.my-region.amazonaws.com/pod-identity-webhook:latest
```

Still open question where did it go, as it's part of managed service as stated in [this comment](https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook/issues/5#issuecomment-587138013)